# How can I get a sequence for differential sheaf on the one point blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X:=\mathbb{P}^2$ and let $\pi : Y(:=\mathbb{Bl}_p) \rightarrow X$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a point $p$. Then we can get a exact sequence for the differential sheaf $\Omega_Y^1$ of $Y$ as:
$$0 \rightarrow {\cal{O}}_Y(-2f) \rightarrow \Omega_Y^1 \rightarrow {\cal{O}}_Y(-2h-f) \rightarrow 0$$
In the above sequence $f$ is a fibre of ruling (as seen $Y$ is  a ruled surface), while $h$ is the negative intersection section. My question is that how I can get this sequence in detail. Maybe it is an easy question, but I cannot get any idea for the first step. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is the exact sequence $0\rightarrow p^*\Omega ^1_{\mathbb{P}^1}\rightarrow \Omega ^1_Y\rightarrow \Omega ^1_{X/Y}\rightarrow 0$ associated to the smooth  fibration $p:Y\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. The question would be more appropriate on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I apologize this misplaced question.